# interfacing php with matlab

Tags: php, matlab

i have an html file test.html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="computeSIFT.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

the above code when run calls the computeSIFT.php file which inturn calls matlab to do the processing on an input image

```
//computeSIFT.php
<?php
#function for streaming file to client
function streamFile($location, $filename, $mimeType='application/octet-    stream')
{ if(!file_exists($location))
{ header ("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
return;
}

$size=filesize($location);
$time=date('r',filemtime($location));
#html response header
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');   
header("Content-Type: $mimeType"); 
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');  
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length:'.($size));
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
header("Last-Modified: $time");
header('Connection: close');      

ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($location);

}


#Main script


#<1>set target path for storing photo uploads on the server
$photo_upload_path = "C:/wamp/www/upload/";
$photo_upload_path = $photo_upload_path. basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']     ['name']); 
#<2>set target path for storing result on the server
$processed_photo_output_path = "c:/wamp/www/output/processed_";
$processed_photo_output_path = $processed_photo_output_path. basename(      $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
$downloadFileName = 'processed_' . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

#<3>modify maximum allowable file size to 10MB and timeout to 300s
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');  
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');  
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);  
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);  

#<4>Get and stored uploaded photos on the server
if(copy($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $photo_upload_path)) {

#<5> execute matlab image processing algorithm
#example: Compute and display SIFT features using VLFeat and Matlab

    $command = "matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nodisplay -r  \"computeSIFT('$photo_upload_path','$processed_photo_output_path');exit\"";
exec($command);

 #<6>stream processed photo to the client
 streamFile($processed_photo_output_path,    $downloadFileName,"application/octet-stream");
    }       
else{

    echo "There was an error uploading the file to $photo_upload_path !";
   }

   ?>
```

.when the html code is tun in the browser it allows the user to select file and upload on the server..however when the php script is called it doesnt call matlab to do the processing.the matlab is supposed to take the input image and compute SIFT of the image.it takes a lot of time and it doesnt show the result.
Is there a way to know if matlab is actualy being called or no?? i referred the following tutorial but it doesnt work properly.can nyone tel me where m going wrong.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

link to the tutorial which i referred 
http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/Tutorial-3-Server-Client-Communication-for-Android.pdf

the contents of output.log file when trying to run matlab program throgh php commands  is as follows

```
Warning: Unable to locate a personal folder for $documents\MATLAB
Warning: Userpath must be an absolute path and must exist on disk.
Exception in thread "FileDecorationCache request queue"       java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Could not get shell folder ID list
at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getFileSystemPath(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.composePathForCsidl(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2.getDesktop(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2.createShellFolder(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.getShellFolder(Unknown Source)
at com.mathworks.jmi.MLFileIconUtils.getNativeFileIcon(MLFileIconUtils.java:235)
at com.mathworks.jmi.MLFileIconUtils.getFileIcon(MLFileIconUtils.java:102)
at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.extensions.basic.DefaultFileInfoProvider$1.run(DefaultFileInfoProvider.java:64)
at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.FileDecorationModel$3$1.run(FileDecorationModel.java:344)
at com.mathworks.util.RequestQueue.execute(RequestQueue.java:105)
at com.mathworks.util.RequestQueue.access$000(RequestQueue.java:22)
at com.mathworks.util.RequestQueue$2.run(RequestQueue.java:75)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not get shell folder ID list
at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getFileSystemPath0(Native Method)
at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$900(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$8.call(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$8.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
{Undefined function 'computeSIFT' for input arguments of
type 'char'.
}
```

Comment: Check the result of your exec like this: exec($command $output,$return_var); var_dump($output); var_dump($return_var);

Comment: I'd suggest to test the matlab-part on the command line before implementing it in the whole php-script. Therefore execute `matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nodisplay -r  \"computeSIFT('path/to/source','path/to/output');exit\"` and inspect the results. If this works, go back into your application.

Comment: @Matt  it doesnt work on the command line.the code works perfectly fine if i open and run it using the matlab editor  ,..however running the file from command line gives an error. infact i also tried running a simple matlab code from the command line but it gives the same error.

Comment: @Matt Error using figure
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option"
in the MATLAB Release Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6', '-browser').

Error in computeSIFT (line 45)
h  = figure(1);                                                                                                                 this is the error which  i get

Comment: **First:** The tutorial most likely uses Linux on the server. In Linux, options like `-nodesktop` and `-nodisplay` are available. For Windows these options do not appear in the documentation [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html). **Second:** In newer versions (Linux) there are no graphics available when using the `-nojvm` option. This can be found [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html).

Comment: @Matt thanx a lot for ur help..i can run d matlab code from the command line but executing the command through php doesnt work!

Comment: Does it work in the command line with the exact arguments like in the php-script? Try to execute without variables in a php-script (use only a string and define everything on your own). Does it work then?

Comment: @Matt yea it works with those arguments.i wrote a php scripts which only does the work of executing dt command..but stil it doesnt work..this is d command which i gave in command line->matlab -r \"computeSIFT

('c:/wamp/www/upload/original.jpg','c:/wa
mp/www/upload/test1.jpg');\"  which is same as the command in php .the php script is as follows                                                                   <?php  exec("matlab -r \"computeSIFT('c:/wamp/www/upload/original.jpg','c:/wamp/www/upload/test1.jpg');\"");
?>

Comment: Could it be that `computeSIFT` is not in the right path, so it cannot be accessed over the command line command in the php-script? `Use -logfile output.log` as an additional option and inspect the file to get errors/warnings.

Comment: @Matt yes when i used the -logfile command the output.log file showed some errors..the path is not correct i guess. i have edited the question and posted the contents of output.log there. can u plz check and suggest any solution?

Comment: Add an user path with the documentation [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/userpath.html). Put the function `computeSIFT` in that folder and retry...

Comment: @Matt i created a folder in c:(c:/matlab1) and changed the userpath to that and also copied 'computeSIFT' there..when i run the command from the command line the working directory is c:\users\sayali. so i changed the working directory of php to d same using chdir..i tried running the php file and i get the following error in d log file ->Warning: Unable to locate a personal folder for $documents\MATLAB
Warning: Userpath must be an absolute path and must exist on disk.

Comment: Set the path using `userpath('C:\matlab1')`. Use the backslash-character since I don't know if the slash-character works for that. Then execute `path`. The first line should be your folder! If the userpath is not saved for the next session, fix it by executing `savepath`.

Comment: @Matt yea i did that..but stil i get the following error in the output.log file                                Warning: Unable to locate a personal folder for $documents\MATLAB
Warning: Userpath must be an absolute path and must exist on disk.

Comment: Ok, you can consult the manual and try to fix this problem. Since it is only a warning, it might not affect the execution of `computeSIFT`.